# How to add a property to each item of a JArray?

Tags: c#

How would i add a property to each item of a JArray, in one line? I'm looking for something like this, using LINQ...

```
myJArray.Select(item => item.Add("property", "value"))
```

I'd do this in Ruby (something like) this:

```
myJArray.each { |item| item.add('property', 'value') }
```

Comment: What do you have against a `foreach` statement, which would express your intention very clearly?

Comment: I come from Ruby; need I say more?

Comment: One liners should be used sparingly, and only if it makes the code more expressive/readable (which is rarely the case). Jon Skeet makes an excellent point, why not use a `foreach`? The problem with using LINQ in these situations is that due to deferred execution, you have to enumerate over the collection AFTER your LINQ statements to even get the desired results...

Comment: @SPFiredrake Good point about deferred execution; however, this is a non-issue in my current situation.

Comment: @ChadJohnson: LINQ is a **query** language. If `JArray` would inherit from `List<T>` you could use [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but that's not the case.

Comment: @ChadJohnson: You should be aiming for readability, which isn't the same as brevity. There's often a correlation, but it's not automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Json.Net

```
jarray.ToList().ForEach(item => item["property"] = "xx");
```

But as already said, I don't think this is better than `foreach`

--EDIT--

An extension method can also be considered

```
jarray.Exec(item => item["property"] = "xx");

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void Exec<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,Action<T> action)
    {
        if (list == null) return;
        foreach (var item in list)
            action(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This creates a copy from an existing collection just to be able to use an extension method that is not the best choice here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Of course I know, but a solution(?) for one-liners